# Using startswith against tuple, return matched string in Python

Tags: python, string, startswith

I'm using the startswith function in Python to clean up a passage of text.
I have a list of 530k strings which represent a persons interpretation of a conversation, I'm trying to strip the first word out if it exists within a list.

To do this I first need to identify that the string contains one of the items in the categories list (which is easy) but then I need to return the item from the categories list as well.

Pseudo-code as follows:

```
s = 'item1: hello my name is roastbeeef'
categories = ['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5']

if s.startswith(tuple(categories)):
     print('ok')
```

So right now the above function will return 'ok' if s starts with 'item1', but what I really want it to do is return 'item1'

Comment: use `for`-loop and check every word separatelly.

Comment: Will the word always be followed by a colon?

Answer (score 3):

Using regex is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = 'item1: hello my name is roastbeeef'
categories = ['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5']
pattern = re.compile(r"(\b{}\b)".format("|".join(categories))) #--> (\bitem1|item2|item3|item4|item5\b) 
m = pattern.match(s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))  # --> item1
```

Comment: Should probably escape all categories just in case `map(re.escape, categories)`

Comment: This works, but it should be noted that it's tricky when you have multiple matches. For example, with `categories = ['item1','item1:','item3','item4','item5']` (the first and second entry would register as `True` in a `startswith`), I think this will only give you one group

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with `startswith()` then you could do the following:

```
s = 'item1: hello my name is roastbeeef'
categories = ['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5']

words = [c for c in categories if s.startswith(c)]
if words:
    print(words[0])
```

The output in this case is:

```
item1
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if `s = 'item11: some_string'` - the result would be `item1`. Peter Wood's solution would handle it correctly

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the word will be followed by a colon:

```
word = s.split(':', 1)[0]
if word in categories:
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
s = 'item1: hello my name is roastbeeef'
categories = ['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5']

list_of_booleans = list(map(s.startswith, categories))

list_of_items = list(filter(s.startswith, categories))  # Items where cond is True
```

Comment: Your answer would be way better if you included some explanation in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly split with ':' the string that satisfies the condition and then take the first element of the resulting list:

```
s = 'item1: hello my name is roastbeeef'
categories = ['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5']

if s.startswith(tuple(categories)):
    print(s.split(':')[0])
```

This assumes that the word is followed by a colon. In case it is followed e.g. by a space you would use `split()` instead of `split(':')`

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the fastest solution but you could always just iterate through with a for loop:

```
s = 'item1: hello my name is roastbeeef'
categories = ['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5']

for val in categories:
    if s.startswith(val):
        print(val)
```